# disable background painting

Tags: c#, paint, flicker

I'm using visual studio 2008

I have a control that dispays a processed image.  Whenever the processing parameters are changed, I'd like to update this picture, but without flickering.  If I could prevent windows from blanking the area before I paint, the flicker should, for the most part go away.

Question is, how to do this?

Something like:
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
Should do it, except that requires me to subclass the TableLayoutPanel control (something I spent an hour trying to do), and with what I achieved, that had no effect.

Is there an easy way to turn off background painting of my control?

Comment: Have you set the DoubleBuffered property of your control to true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried overriding the `OnPaintBackground` event and doing nothing?

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
}
```

Comment: Works. Now I just have to figure out how to subclass the control  without screwing up the forms editor!

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
this.SuspendLayout();
// do update here
this.ResumeLayout();
```

Clarification: `this` is the form

Comment: I'm only updating what image i want to paint.  I'm not actually changing anything about the form, just invalidating it so that it will get repainted with the new image.  The problem is that the background gets cleared before I paint, so it flickers.

Comment: I see. Sorry for the confusion on my part.